# Create a search bar in Firestore retrieved data in React and add a functionality of Edit/Update & Delete buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Below is my code, as of now its working perfectly but I am not able to add a search bar in
it. I am new to the React.js I tried many solutions but didn't get the solution and also I need a functionality for update and delete buttons. thanks in advance

```
import React from "react";
import { db } from "../firebase";
import "../App.css";

function TillDateData() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await db.collection("contacts").orderBy("createdDate").get();
      setContacts(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="myclass">
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            <th scope="col">City</th>
            <th scope="col">Contact No.</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {Object.keys(contacts).map((id) => {
            return (
              <tr key={id}>
                <td>{contacts[id].name}</td>
                <td>{contacts[id].email}</td>
                <td>{contacts[id].city}</td>
                <td>{contacts[id].contact}</td>
                <td>{contacts[id].createdDate}</td>
                <td>
                  <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
export default TillDateData;
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { db, fire } from "../firebase";
import "../App.css";

function TillDateData() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);
  const [contactsData, setContactsData] = useState(users); //iterate this in table

  const deleteContact = (id) => {
    db.collection('users').doc(id).delete()
  };
  
  const changeSearch = (val) => {
    setSearch(val);
    if (val != "") {
      setContactsData(
        users.filter((contact) => {
          contact.name.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase()) ||
            contact.email.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase()) ||
            contact.city.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase()) ||
            contact.number.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase());
        })
      );
    } else {
      setContactsData(users);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await db.collection("users").orderBy("createdDate").get();
      setUsers(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => changeSearch(e.target.value)} />

      <div className="myclass">
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Email</th>
              <th scope="col">City</th>
              <th scope="col">Contact No.</th>
              <th scope="col">Date</th>
              <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {Object.keys(contactsData).map((id) => {
              return (
                <tr key={id}>
                  <td>{users[id].name}</td>
                  <td>{users[id].email}</td>
                  <td>{users[id].city}</td>
                  <td>{users[id].number}</td>
                  <td>{users[id].createdDate}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                      onClick={()=> deleteContact(contact[id].id)}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default TillDateData;
```

just changed some variables remaining same

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of struggle I found a way how to add a search bar functionality in firestore retrieved data. here is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { db } from "../firebase";
import "../App.css";

function RetrieveData() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [filteredContacts, setFilteredContacts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await db.collection("contacts").orderBy("createdDate").get();
      setContacts(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredContacts(
      contacts.filter(
        (user) =>
          user.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
          user.city.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      )
    );
  }, [search, contacts]);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Contact Details</h1>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
          onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        {filteredContacts.map((contact) => [
          <ol>
            <b>Consumer Details :</b> {<br />}
            {contact.name},{<br />}
            {contact.email},{<br />}
            {contact.city},{<br />}
            {contact.contact},{<br />}
          </ol>,
        ])}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default RetrieveData;
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I was struggling on this same issue for hours.

Answer (score 0):

For delete an update try the following code

```
const deleteContact = (id) => {
  //Delete contact with the passed id
}//same for update or edit contacts

<tr>
 ....
  <td><button onClick={()=> deleteContact(contact[id].id)}></td>//same for 
    update
</tr>
```

**Search Bar**

For search bar Do following steps

1- Make search state

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([])//used just to store contacts from api
const [contactsData, setContactsData] = useState(contacts)//iterate this in table
```

2- Write an searchChange handler

```
const changeSearch = (val) => {
   setSearch(val)
   if(val!=''){
   setContactsData(contacts.filter(constact => {
       contact.name.includes(val) ||
       contact.fname.includes(val)//same other fields added by following OR 
       condition
   }))
   }
   else{
      setContactsData(contacts)
   }
}
```

3- Make a search text field

```
<input type='text' onChange={(e)=> changeSearch(e.target.value)}
```

**Note:** use Objects.keys(contactsData).map after updation

**Update and Delete function**

1- for update

```
const UpdateContent = (id) => {
  //call an api that delete the content from DB(firebase) for the provided id in parameters or in body.
}
```

component:

```
<tr>
```

**Delete functionality also describe in the top section of answer**
.....
<button onClick={() => UpdateContent(content[i].id)}/>

Comment: thank you for answering... it would be great if you give a complete code with conditions and it should get back to its normal list after clearing search bar...bcoz am beginner in react

Comment: Thank you clearing search bar working but searching is not working , when i serach whole list is disappearing, I included all the fields  like this 
contact.name.includes(val)
 ||contact.email.includes(val) ||
            contact.city.includes(val) ||
            contact.number.includes(val) ||
            contact.createdDate.includes(val);

Comment: try to convert both the search text and data text to upper case may be this is the issue like  contact.name.toUppercase().includes(val.toUppercase()) may be it helps

Comment: please show me the search function you are using and the data for which it filter result

Comment: And for delete and update I have update the question

Comment: ok just put value tag inside input field of search like

<input type='text' value={search} onChange={(e) => changeSearch(e.target.value)}/>

Comment: one more thing do you verify that when empty value of search text receive in changeSearch function can it goes to else part properly.

Comment: I added value={search} but nothing changed, before searching only the list is disappeared , when I type something and clear it then the list is appearing, Now I am searching again the list is disappeared again. how to check else part of changeSearch I didn't get, I have the same code above

Comment: in your useEffect hook after setUser(...) write setContactData(users) also
and for checking else part try to console what you recieve in value parameter of changeSearch function

Comment: Ali Faiz please help me in solving search bar in react. still am stucked in that. Itried other solutions, if the data is inside the application i.e in arrays/object then search bar is  working but in firestore retrieved data search bar is not working .

Comment: hy @ar.saud, I think you should use server side searching which mostly recommended and in my search i found it best approach from search logic in client side. By using server side searching you just need to pass query in your request body or in URL as param and in your server side just return the query result after filtering.

Comment: I found a way how to add a search bar functionality in firestore retrieved data. here is my code.. I would like to thank @Ali Faiz who helped me.

Comment: can you mark my answer as accepted if it really help you.